# If torrent contain multiple files, how to know what piece correspond to each file?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm building a BitTorrent client application in Java and I have 2 small question:

1. Can torrent contain folders? recursively?
2. If a torrent contains `n` files (not directories - for simplicity), do I need to create `n` files with their corresponding size? When I receive a piece from a peer, how do I know to which file it (the piece) belong?

For example, here is a torrent which contains 2 files:

```
TorrentInfo{Created By: ruTorrent (PHP Class - Adrien Gibrat)
Main tracker: http://tracker.hebits.net:35777/tracker.php?do=announce&passkey=5d3ab309eda55c1e7183975099958ab2
Comment: null
Info_hash: c504216ca4a113d26f023a10a1249ca3a6217997
Name: Veronica.2017.1080p.BluRay.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.x264-HDH
Piece Length: 16777216
Pieces: 787
Total Size: null
Is Single File Torrent: false
File List:
TorrentFile{fileLength=13202048630, fileDirs=[Veronica.2017.1080p.BluRay.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.x264-HDH.mkv]}
TorrentFile{fileLength=62543, fileDirs=[Veronica.2017.1080p.BluRay.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.x264-HDH.srt]}
```

The docs doesn't say much: https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what you are doing is similar to mine...

The following bold fonts are important to your questions.

1.yes; no

**Info in Multiple File Mode**

**name**: the name of the *directory* in which to store all the files. This is purely advisory. (string)

**path**: a list containing one or more string elements that together represent the path and filename. Each element in the list corresponds to either a directory name or (in the case of the final element) the filename. For example, a the file "dir1/dir2/file.ext" would consist of three string elements: "dir1", "dir2", and "file.ext". This is encoded as a bencoded list of strings such as l4:*dir*14:*dir*28:file.exte

**Info in Single File Mode**

**name**: the filename. This is purely advisory. (string)

Filename includes floder name.

2.maybe;

Whether you need to create n files with their corresponding size depend on whether you need to download n files.

**Peer wire protocol (TCP)**

**piece**:

The piece message is variable length, where X is the length of the block. The payload contains the following information:

index: integer specifying the zero-based piece index

**begin**: integer specifying the zero-based byte offset within the piece

block: block of data, which is a subset of the piece specified by index.

For the purposes of piece boundaries in the **multi-file case**, consider the file data as **one long continuous stream**, composed of the concatenation of each file **in the order listed in the *files* list**. The number of pieces and their boundaries are then determined in the same manner as the case of a single file. Pieces may overlap file boundaries.

*I am sorry for my english, because I am not native speaker...*

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I hadn't a chance to look into it. But I will definitely do shortly. Thanks again for such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can torrent contain folders? recursively?

Yes.
Sortof. In BEP3 Nested directories are mapped into path elements, i.e. `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.ext` is represented as path: `["dir1", "dir2", "dir3", "file.ext"]` in the file list. BEP52 changes this to a tree-based structure more closely resembling a directory tree.

> If a torrent contains n files (not directories - for simplicity), do I need to create n files with their corresponding size? When I receive a piece from a peer, how do I know to which file it (the piece) belong?

The bittorrent wire protocol deals with a contiguous address space of bytes which are grouped into fixed-sized pieces. How a client stores those bytes locally is in principle up to the implementation. But if you want to store it in the file layout described in the `.torrent` then you have to calculate a mapping between the pieces address space and file offsets. In BEP3 files are not aligned to piece boundaries, so a single piece can straddle multiple files. BEP 47 and BEP 52 aim to simplify this by introducing padding files or implicit alignment gaps respectively.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand you or my question wasn't clear so I will ask again. In case the torrent contains multiple files, when I receive a piece with the following details: `index: x`, `offset: y` and `bytes: z`, to which file, the received piece belongs to?

Comment: As of BEP3 you multiple index by piece-size, add offset and put it in the piece address space, then look up the position in the files as if they were concatenated in the order listed in the torrent.